# Is FL_ENC_RAW a valid flag for ZipArchive::addFromString?

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I have a "string" variable that contains binary jpeg data. I want to add this jpeg to a zip file. According to [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfromstring.php) the `$flags` parameter is a

> Bitmask consisting of `ZipArchive::FL_OVERWRITE`, `ZipArchive::FL_ENC_GUESS`, `ZipArchive::FL_ENC_UTF_8`, `ZipArchive::FL_ENC_CP437`.

`ZipArchive::FL_ENC_GUESS` would probably work, but it sounds like that is going to try to heuristically guess encoding based on the contents of my variable. If I want to be explicit, should I set `$flags` to `ZipArchive::FL_ENC_UTF_8` or `ZipArchive::FL_ENC_CP437`? Between the 2, `ZipArchive::FL_ENC_UTF_8` seems like the better choice.

`ZipArchive::FL_ENC_RAW` seems like what I should really be using, but according to the docs this is not a valid flag for this particular function. Is this an omission? As best I can tell it's not listed as a valid flag for any function.

Comment: I'm 90% sure that the encoding is about the file's name itself, and not the contents, although this is not obvious from the PHP documentation, nor the underlying [zlib documentation](https://libzip.org/documentation/zip_file_add.html). There's zero reason for zip to interpret the contents of the stream (that I can think of, at least). Looking at the PHP [tests](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/74859783398a5fba177cdfd39cbf299abf327fa0/ext/zip/tests/oo_add_encoding.phpt) for those constants, this seems to confirm that, too.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I agree with your assessment based on libzip's description of the flag as "Interpret **name** as UTF-8." If you want to post that as an answer I would accept it. If not I will write up my own in a day or so. (I'm trying to be reputation-honest, since you found the answer)

Comment: I'm okay with you writing an answer an accepting it. I think this could be submitted to the docs team, too, to more explicitly state it. I don't know if the constants are used in multiple places, but if they are, their definitions might be correct. But definitely on the `addFromString` (and probably a couple of other places) it should be noted that `FL_ENC_*` are about the file/directory name, and not the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ZipArchive::addFromString](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfromstring.php) is calling zip_file_add [under the hood](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/90b7bde61507cee1c6b37f153909d72f5b203b8c/ext/zip/php_zip.c#L1943). If we take a look at [the documentation for that function in libzip](https://libzip.org/documentation/zip_file_add.html) we find more descriptive explanations for what each of the flags is doing:

> - ZIP_FL_ENC_UTF_8: Interpret name as UTF-8.
> - ZIP_FL_ENC_CP437: Interpret name as code page 437 (CP-437).

`ZipArchive::FL_ENC_UTF_8` and `ZipArchive::FL_ENC_CP437` affect how the *filename* (aka the `$name` parameter) is interpreted, not the data inside the file itself. The contents of the file are processed the same regardless of if the data is UTF-8, CP-437, binary data, or anything else.

This is confirmed in the [php tests](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/74859783398a5fba177cdfd39cbf299abf327fa0/ext/zip/tests/oo_add_encoding.phpt) for this library where these 4 lines

```php
$zip->addEmptyDir(chr(0x82), ZipArchive::FL_ENC_CP437);
$zip->addEmptyDir('è', ZipArchive::FL_ENC_UTF_8);
$zip->addFromString(chr(0x91), __FILE__, ZipArchive::FL_ENC_CP437);
$zip->addFromString('€', __FILE__, ZipArchive::FL_ENC_UTF_8);
```

are expected to produce files with the following names

- é (corresponding to page 437 character hex:82 dec:130)
- è
- æ (corresponding to page 437 character hex:91 dec:145)
- €